# Autohotkey concerning Websocket | Winhttp and stuff question

Tags: websocket, autohotkey

Trying to get trading information via websocket method. There are many guides and manuals for other languages, I would like to get it via Autohotkey preferably.

Below is the code that I am using when receiving info with Autohotkey.

```
Get_Price(Target_Site, Target_Coin, Price_Type = "KRW") {
if (Target_Site = "UpBit") {
API_Url := "https://crix-api-endpoint.upbit.com/v1/crix/candles/minutes/10?code=CRIX.UPBIT."
}

Result_URL := API_Url "" Price_Type "-" Target_Coin
Result_Json := Get_WinHttp(Result_URL)
    RegExMatch(Result_Json, "tradePrice"`":(.*?)\.", Result)  ;If(Target_Coin="BTT") Or (Target_Coin="DOGE") If(Target_Coin="BTT") Or (Target_Coin="DOGE")RegExMatch(Result_Json, "tradePrice"`":(.*?)\,", Result)
Return Result1                   
}
```

It seems like the approach above was kinda more explicit and easy compared to Websocket. Only thing I had to was forming right url with my info and sending that url and get the result from the website.

But, when it comes to websocket, I know of the right url, right info to send, but don't know how I can send and .. yeah how.

Url : `wss://api.upbit.com/websocket/v1`
What to send : `'[{"ticket":"test1243563456"},{"type":"trade",{"type":"trade","codes":["KRW-BTC", "KRW-ETH"]}]'`

How : I don't know. But I happen to come across some interesting AHK example, I am wishing I can modifying this. Will appreciate if you can have a look and guide me if possible.

```
#Include, Websocket.Ahk

class Example extends WebSocket
{
    OnOpen(Event)
    {
        InputBox, Data, WebSocket, Enter some text to send through the websocket.
        If (ErrorLevel==1)
            this.Close()
        this.Send(Data)
    }
    
    OnMessage(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, % "Received Data: " Event.data
        new Example("wss://echo.websocket.org/")
    }
    
    OnClose(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, Websocket Closed
        this.Disconnect()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, in AHK v1 you escape quotes by doing a double quote `""`.
Here `` "tradePrice"`":(.*?)\." `` your resulting string has a double quote in it by pretty much sheer luck.
Actually it's supposed to be done like this: `"tradePrice"":(.*?)\."`.
You'll need to correctly escape quotes in what you're going to do next.
Also, since you have a json response, you might want to parse the json and use it how it's *supposed to be used*.<sup>[(See AHK JSON/Jxon)](https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON)</sup>

So about the websocket.
Personally I'd say G33kDude's example<sup>[(Github)](https://github.com/G33kDude/WebSocket.ahk)</sup> explains it pretty well, but maybe you were thrown off by the object oriented code style choice he's made for it.
It's not that easy to understand if you're not experienced with OOP/OOP AHK I guess.

Here's an example for calling an echo websocket with the data you wanted to send.

```
#Include WebSocket.ahk

New HelperClass("wss://echo.websocket.org/")

class HelperClass extends WebSocket
{
    OnOpen(Event)
    {
        DataToSend := "[{""ticket"":""test1243563456""},{""type"":""trade"",{""type"":""trade"",""codes"":[""KRW-BTC"", ""KRW-ETH""]}]"
        this.Send(DataToSend)
    }
    
    OnMessage(event)
    {
        MsgBox, % "Received a message!:`n" Event.data
        this.Close()
    }
    
    OnClose(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, Websocket Closed
        this.Disconnect()
    }
    
    OnError(Event)
    {
        MsgBox, Websocket Error
    }
    
    __Delete()
    {
        MsgBox, Exiting
        ExitApp
    }
}
```

You have to make this class that extends the WebSocket class due to how it's designed, but it's actually pretty convenient if you know OOP (AHK).

So here's how it works:

1. `New HelperClass("wss://echo.websocket.org/")`
   You prepare the behind the scenes magic open a websocket connection to the specified websocket
2. The `OnOpen()` function runs in your `HelperClass` once the magic has been prepared
3. `this.Send(DataToSend)`
   You call the `Send` function (which if found inside the `WebSocket` class) and pass in the data you want
4. You receive a response message (`OnMessage()` runs in your `HelperClass`), or maybe you receive an error (`OnError()` runs in your `HelperClass`)
5. The connection closes, so `OnClose()` runs in your `HelperClass`.
   And you also want to reset the behind the scenes magic by calling `Disconnect()` function inside the `WebSocket` class by doing `this.Disconnect()`

<sup>(When I say inside `HelperClass` or inside `WebSocket` class, it's actually incorrect because they're kind of the same class, you're just extending `WebSocket` class with your `HelperClass`)</sup>

So that's about it.

---

Misc notes:
Download the WebSocket class from G33kDude's GitHub and include the WebSocket.ahk file to your own script with `#Include`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm)</sup>.

G33kDude example script uses `#Include ../WebSocket.ahk` to include it, because his example script is in a subfolder, so he goes back one folder with `..` and then specifies the file to include.

Also note how the quotation marks are correctly escaped in the `DataToSend` variable.

Comment: Too late to check your answer, it is great!

Comment: Very helpful really